# How to customize image mark width and height to act as barchart bars in altair?

Tags: altair

I am exploring the image mark in altair. I tried to make bar charts with image as bars,

```
source = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'b': [28, 12, 77],
    'url': ['https://vega.github.io/vega-datasets/data/7zip.png', 
            'https://vega.github.io/vega-datasets/data/gimp.png', 
            'https://vega.github.io/vega-datasets/data/ffox.png']
})

init = alt.Chart(source).mark_image(
    # width= 50,

    ).encode(
    x='a',
    y='b',
    url = 'url',
    size=alt.Size('b:N', scale=None),
    # color = 'a'
).properties(
    width=512,
    height=512
).configure_axis(
    grid=False
)
```

my current result is like this:
[image]

but I want to make the height of images corresponding to y value while keep same width, like this:

[image]

Am I able to achieve this by altair? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation mentions an `aspect` parameter which will do what you are looking for, but I couldn't find an example.
Vega-lite, on which Altair is based, allows changing the image aspect ratio as seen [here](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/marks/image/). You can try looking at the source of the example there and figure out how to make it work in Altair.